# Can I convert a fat32 disk image to NTFS, and how?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, fat32, disk-image

I have just imaged a FAT32 disk drive on a NTFS disk drive.
I'm aware I could have imaged on a FAT32 HDD and convert it later, but I figured it out too late and I'm trying to save processing time (I have other stuff to do on both of my computers).

The disk image is a .dig, made with DrvImagerXP.

So my question is, is there any tool out there that converts disk images?

Comment: What *sort* of disk images? Without mentioning details of the image format and program used to create it, there's insufficient information to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an ISO? Find a tool to mount it, then use the built-in `convert` utility.

Comment: No, it's a .dig so I decided to split my file into parts with HJSplit and partition a disk where i'll put the parts and convert them one by one. I'm going to accept your answer though if you specify a mounting tool that has a built-in convert utility (since the one I have doesn't seem to have any) so I can try it and check this as accepted :)

Comment: How do you create an ISO with a FAT32 file system? Even if you can, will `convert` be able to modify the file system inside a mounted ISO? Which tool mounts ISOs in a writeable manner? Have you ever tried something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some info about the topic that may be pertinent. It says to

"Now go to Start Menu >Run >cmd (Command Prompt)  and Type the following command:
convert Y: /fs:ntfs   (Where “Y” is your USB drive letter). 
This will convert the USB Flash drive from a fat32 to a NTFS file system"

Here is the [Link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Install-Windows7-on-to-a-Acer-Netbook-from-a-USB-F/step2/Convert-Flash-Drive-from-Fat32-to-NTFS-file-system/)

Comment: I do not have any removable devices that are large enough for my image  and fat32 doesn't take files over 4gigs, my image is 19 gigs.